# regrouping/reassigning raw data

Tags: r

I am trying to reassign raw scores. For more context, I had 10 people rate 100 items on a scale of 0-100. What I am wanting to do is re-group the raw scores into 1-5. So, for example, converting raw scores 0-20 = 1 ; 21-40 = 2 ; 41-60 = 3 ; 61-80 = 4 ; 81-100 = 5.
I am new to Rstudio and am lost on how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cut`

```
as.integer(cut(scores, breaks = c(-Inf, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100)))
```

or with `findInterval`

```
findInterval(scores, c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
scores <- sample(0:100, 20, replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'scores' in your script exactly? Because in my data set, each column is a different "item" that was rated so I'm not sure how to give the general command to R saying reassign to every number in this csv file. 
Again, new to R...sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: @TeebEE33 I meant the `scores` as a object name.  I updated with the data I used

Answer (score 0):

You may divide the scores by 20 and use `ceiling`.

```
df$group <- ceiling(df$score/20)
df

#   people item score group
#1       1    3    90     5
#2       2   10    91     5
#3       3    2    69     4
#4       4    8    99     5
#5       5    6    57     3
#6       6    9    92     5
#7       7    1     9     1
#8       8    7    93     5
#9       9    5    72     4
#10     10    4    26     2
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(people = 1:10, item = sample(10), score = sample(100, 10))
```